# Django backwards reference not created

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Here are my models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(a, related_name="foo")
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

In the Django shell, I run the following:

```
>>> x = A(1)
>>> y = B(a=x, bar=1)
>>> x
<A: A object>
>>> y
<B: B object>
>>> x.__dict__
{'foo': 0, '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x3772d10>, 'id': 1}
>>> y.__dict__
{'bar': 1, '_a_cache': <A: A object>, '_state':<django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x3772d90>, 'id': None, 'a_id': 1}
```

Why doesn't `related_name` create a `"foo"` field in the `A` model?

Comment: Did you actually have problems using `x.foo`? Django creates an object descriptor on `A`, and object descriptors are _not_ included in `__dict__`.

Comment: Oh, interesting. My problem was with the field, not with x.foo, but maybe it's related?

Comment: My problem was with the field literally not being in place, i.e. can't edit it in admin. Should I be able to?

Comment: Not by default. You could use an [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).